# How to make Django's DateTimeField optional?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement a to-do-list website to practice using Django. In models.py, I have a class called `Item` to represent a to-do item. In it, I have the following line:

```
due_date = models.DateTimeField(required=False)
```

`due_date` is meant to be an optional field in case the user has a deadline for some to-do item. The problem is that the line above gives me a `TypeError` due to unexpected keyword argument 'required'.

So, it seems that I cannot use the keyword argument 'required' for `DateTimeField`. Is there any way I can make a `DateTimeField` optional? Or is there a standard implementation for the problem I am having?

Comment: `required` is only for *form* fields. Model fields use `blank=True`, which must be combined with `null=True` for a `DateTimeField` in order to allow a NULL value to be stored for the column in the database. Otherwise, you'd get an `IntegrityError`.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

"required" is a valid argument for Django forms. For models, you want the keyword args `blank=True` (for the admin) and `null=True` (for the database).

Comment: Ah, so I got forms and models mixed up. Oops.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between `required`, `blank`, and `null`.

Comment: IIRC `blank=True, null=True` is not recommended for text fields because then you can have two "nulls": `''` and `NULL`, but does that not apply for the date-typed field?

Comment: It's indeed better to avoid NULL on text fields, and it's indeed different for date/datetime fields which are not supposed to accept the empty string as a valid value.

Comment: I always thought ```blank=True``` implied ```null=True```

Answer (score 41):

Use
  `due_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)`

Check [Field Options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#field-options) for more information.

Comment: Do we need to add `required=False` too, or are these two enough? Any difference if we add it or not?

Comment: @halilpazarlama You don't need `required=False` in your model field and I it is not even a  valid keyword argument in a model field definition. `required=*` can be used in form fields and still you won't need if you already have `blank=True` in your model field definition.

Comment: Oh. I should have read the other answers more thoroughly. Thanks though :)

Answer (score -2):

Before you save the form you need to set the datefields to None. Its works for me

```
class ActividadEdit(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView ):
model = Ges_Actividad
form_class = GestionActividadesUpdateForm
template_name = 'seguimiento_formula/actividades_seguimiento_update.html'

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    self.object = self.get_object()
    id_actividad = kwargs['pk']
    instancia_nivel = self.model.objects.get(id=id_actividad)
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=instancia_nivel)
    id_usuario_actual = self.request.user.id  # obtiene id usuario actual

    try:
        periodo_actual = Glo_Periodos.objects.get(id_estado=1)
    except Glo_Periodos.DoesNotExist:
        return None

    try:
        id_jefatura = Ges_Jefatura.objects.get(Q(id_user=id_usuario_actual) & Q(id_periodo=periodo_actual.id))
    except Ges_Jefatura.DoesNotExist:
        return None

    try:
        usuario_controlador = Ges_Controlador.objects.get(id_jefatura=id_jefatura.id)
    except Ges_Controlador.DoesNotExist:
        return None
   #**before you save the form you need to set the datefields to None. Its works for me**.
    form.instance.fecha_real_termino = None
    form.instance.fecha_real_termino = None
    form.instance.fecha_real_termino = None


    if form.is_valid():

        if self.request.session['id_orden'] == 2:
            id_objetivo = Ges_Objetivo_Tactico.objects.get(id=self.request.session['id_objetivo'])
            form.instance.id_objetivo_tactico = id_objetivo

        if self.request.session['id_orden'] == 3:
            id_objetivo = Ges_Objetivo_TacticoTN.objects.get(id=self.request.session['id_objetivo'])
            form.instance.id_objetivo_tacticotn = id_objetivo

        if self.request.session['id_orden'] == 4:
            id_objetivo = Ges_Objetivo_Operativo.objects.get(id=self.request.session['id_objetivo'])
            form.instance.id_objetivo_operativo = id_objetivo

        form.save()
        request.session['message_class'] = "alert alert-success"
        messages.success(self.request, "Los datos fueron actualizados correctamente!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/actividades/detalle/' + str(self.request.session['id_objetivo']))
    else:
        request.session['message_class'] = "alert alert-danger"
        messages.error(self.request,
                       "Error interno: No se ha creado el registro. Comuníquese con el administrador.")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/actividades/detalle/' + str(self.request.session['id_objetivo']))
```